# angularjs how to receive json message sent from tomcat servlet

Tags: java, json, angularjs, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to receive json message from servlet based on angular js, but it always fails.

I am using the `$http.post`, but seems it does not work, could someone help me on that?

Here is my servlet code:

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("field_name", "hahaha");

        out.print(jsonObject);
}
```

Here is my js:

```
var sandBoxApp = angular.module('sandboxApp', [])

sandBoxApp.controller('SandBoxCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

    $scope.heads = ['Field name', 'Original value', 'Processed value'];

    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.doClick = function(item, event) {

        var responsePromise = $http.post("HelloWorld");

        responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.fromServer = data;
        });
        responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("AJAX failed!");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you inspected the objects that are passed to the error handler? What do your web server logs show? Or what does the web inspector in your browser show?

Comment: @SunilD. Hi, Sunil, I got the error message says:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @SunilD. Can I email you the code?

Comment: 500 means an error occurred in your server code. Check the web server logs, there is likely a nice stack trace that points out the line that caused the error. Unfortunately, I can't help much more than that, I'm just a client side developer don't know Java well enough.

Comment: You might need to do something like out.print(jsonObject.toString()); Or use Jackson to do object -> json mapping.

Answer (score 0):

out.print(jsonObject.toString()); use this instead of out.print(jsonObject);